# Citrix Receiver app issue

Tags: citrix-receiver

I have an issue to run any app using Citrix Receiver.
I have MacOS 10.11 and Citrix Receiver 12.9.1
I tried to use Safari and Chrome and both didn't work.
Here are the steps:

1. I login into the store.
2. I start any application from the store
3. I see that it started and I see a message 'starting application' and it's spinning i.e. processing
4. It freezes at this point. It does not go ahead.
   I cleaned browsers, re-installed Citrix Receiver and etc. but nothing has changed and it failed to load app i.e. complete it.
   Any idea what could be the issue?
   Note: this morning I was able to login and start with no issue but after I shutdown MacBook and started it again ... Citrix does not work for me anymore
   Thanks